# How can I create a CGRect with a new origin but utilizing the existing size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

In objective-c I am often updating the frames of my views during animations. I currently have a messy solution to doing so:

```
CGPoint newOrigin = CGPointMake(25.0, 25.0);    
view.frame = CGRectMake(newOrigin.x, newOrigin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
```

What I'm looking for is a simple convenience method that works like this:

```
view.frame = CGRectWithNewOrigin(view.frame, newOrigin);
```

Is there an existing method in the SDK which does this or will I need to define my own?

**Solved: 0x7fffffff has the correct answer but JackWu's suggestion is a better approach:**

The solution offered by Jack Wu solved my problem. The iOS SDK has no method which does this so you will need to define your own inline method to do so. However, utilizing the UIView's center property is a better approach. No need to define an inline function and it also will continue to work if the view has had a transform applied to it.

Comment: To do this, its recommended to set the "center" property instead of the frame, this won't change the size of the view

Comment: Note that as soon as a `transform` is applied, the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. While this might not be a problem with your current setup, manipulating the `center` property as @JackWu suggests might save you a headache down the road.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is indeed the right way to solve my problem in most cases. I will mark the answer from 0x7ffffff as the correct answer but update the question text to mention that it is more appropriate to adjust the center. I ended up using the center property in my own project here. Thanks @JackWu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy enough to define a new inline method just like the ones already being used, like CGRectMake().. What about something like this?

```
static inline CGRect CGRectWithNewOrigin(CGPoint origin, CGRect frame) {
    return CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
}
```

Then use it like you would for any other function of CGRect

```
CGPoint newOrigin = CGPointMake(25.0, 25.0); 
CGRect newRect = CGRectWithNewOrigin(newOrigin, oldRect);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there was already a method that did this or if I would have to just define it myself. Thanks for your answer as now I know it doesn't exist and this is how an equivalent method!

Answer (score 2):

[`CGRectOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectOffset) does the thing (in many but not all cases):

> Returns a rectangle with an origin that is offset from that of the source rectangle.

Comment: Close, but that moves the rect, it doesn't reset the origin.

Comment: @ClayBridges: Yes, but thinking in terms of the position *changes* is often useful when writing the animation code.

Comment: Thanks but I had already tried that one. As Clay points out it effectively translates the rect from it's current origin. It is useful in animation code but in this case it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
view.frame = (CGRect){.origin = newOrigin, .size = view.frame.size};
```

Otherwise, you can just write your own C function, I'm pretty sure one doesn't exist. (I just looked at `CGGeometry.h` for the hundredth time.)

Though it's a little more general than what you are asking for, I've often thought something like this would be useful:

```
static inline CGRect CGRectFromOriginSize(CGPoint origin, CGSize size) {
    return (CGRect){.origin = newOrigin, .size = view.frame.size};;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
CGRect newFrame = view.frame;

newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(25.0, 25.0);

view.frame = newFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CGPoint newOrigin = CGPointMake(25.0, 25.0);

CGRect newFrame = view.frame;
newFrame.origin = newOrigin;


view.frame = newFrame;
```